# How to backup BirdNET?

Tags: backup

I'm using [BirdNET](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tu_chemnitz.mi.kahst.birdnet&hl=en&gl=US) application to collect data about birds. However, the app does not support registration and data synchronisation, or even import/export.

I asked support if they provide the way to backup data, but there is no such way; info from the support:

> Thanks for reaching out to us. Users can save and text/email the sound file of their recordings from the app; however, it does not offer the option of backing up the observations and transfer them to a new device. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Question: How can I backup that data? Is there any app that would do that auto

Comment: On unrooted devices you can only use what the app offers. So if the developers tell you that backup is not supported then that is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to export and import all observations in the BirdNET application now:

**☰** > Show observations > **⋮** > Export Observations

[image]